# Parse the fetched data in C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# and trying to write some code to fetch the webpage and parse it into readable format.

I have fetched the data from webpage using uri

```
var uri2 = new Uri("explame.com")
```

I see the response in format below like this:

```
{"name":"abc" "country":"xyz" "citizenship":"A" [{"pincode":"111", "Dis":"no"] Lot's of data follows something like that
```

There are multiple with attribute "name" and "country" in response. My question is how to fetch the data something like below

```
name:abc
country:xyz
citizenshih:A
pincode 111
dis:no
```

For all attributes in response code.

Comment: That's json, there are tons of parsers and even with a regex can be used, but stick with what tofutim said, Newtonsoft.Json, also known as Json.net

Comment: Is that the *exact* format of the data you're getting?  Because that's JSON-*ish*, but it's not valid JSON and wouldn't be parsed as such.

Comment: @tofutim Would you mind sharing a simple example on how to use Newtonsoft json for above example. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 1):

Is that the exact format of the data you're getting? Because that's JSON-*ish*, but it's not valid JSON and wouldn't be parsed as such.  *If*, however, you are actually getting JSON then you can de-serialize that.

Using something like [Newtonsoft's JSON library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you can fairly trivially [de-serialize JSON into an object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm).  For example, this JSON:

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "country":"xyz",
  "citizenship":"A",
  "someProperty": [
    {
      "pincode":"111",
      "Dis":"no"
    }]
}
```

Might map to these types:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Citizenship { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyOtherClass> SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyOtherClass
{
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
    public string Dis { get; set; }
}
```

In which case de-serializing might be as simple as this:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(receivedJsonString);
            foreach (dynamic o in data)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(o.country);
            }
```